# Android Studio not detecting changes to local module

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have an Android Project consisting of a main module and a local "Utilities" module. The Utilities module is referenced in Gradle with the line "implementation project(path: ':Utilities', configuration: 'default')". The app will compile and run. I recently changed the signature of one of the methods in Utilities to add a parameter and again the app will compile and run. The issue is that Android Studio is highlighting calls in the main app to the changed method with a 'cannot resolve method' error and only hints at versions of the method without the added parameter? I ave done numerous clear cache, restart, cleans etc but to no avail. Any thoughts appreciated.